# How to remove old localhost that goes to wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, apache, xampp, localhost

I installed wordpress locally on my system but uninstalled it recently. Now I have xampp and my apache, mysql all running but when I type localhost in URL it's still the same old localhost:
"Awesome! WordPress is now installed.
          Access WordPress"

How do I change it so Xampp is my localhost?

Comment: Did you delete the site directory and drop the database? Try restarting the server.

Comment: It worked out :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your system and clear your browser cache and also remove your WP database if you want a fresh WP installation

Answer (score 0):

1) go to the xampp directory and you'll find a folder named htdocs there. remove all files from that folder.

2) force restart the browser by pressing ctrl + f5